# Embeding swf file in html page

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, flash

In the code below what is addvariable doing also i need to embed the swf only in my html page and it is not php.Please let me know how to embed the swf file in html page

```
<table border=0 width=100% height=100%>

<tr><td align=center valign=center>




<script type="text/javascript" src="test/swfobject.js"></script>

<div id="test">


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var s = new SWFObject("test.swf?v=10.1.5", "speedtest", "450", "250", "8", "#11");

s.addVariable("upload_extension", "php");

s.write("test");

</script>




</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the URL to your live page?  Others are right, updating your SWFObject is a good idea, but I suspect there is a different issue at hand.  Probably a missing file.

Comment: did that answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice is using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Here is the documentation, I think it is quite straightforward to add it to your site.
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Good luck,
Rob

Comment: Uh, he is using it? Did you read the question beyond the title?

Comment: He is, thanks. I think you should switch to version 2+ as it is more effective than the previous one and loads of issues are solved by it. Rob

Comment: You are less than helpful, really.

Comment: I think you are simply amazing. Really.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an old version of swfobject. The addVariable method adds an attribute to the object element that swfobject creates. Not sure what the upload_extension attribute does, probably a flash variable the flash application needs.

You should use the latest version of [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) and check out the [javascript api](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="test/swfobject.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF("test/test.swf", "speedtest", "450", "250", "8");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="speedtest"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Download SWFobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: @Hulk are you sure the file is linked correctly? ie. that it's in the "test" folder?